# crosstab with 2 (or more) row names

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table, crosstab, transpose

I'm trying to transpose a table which has 2 row names.
Postgres documentation mentions the `crosstab()` function being able to only handle 1 row name, but I have 2 row names, like first name and last name.

my intital table is:

```
fn |  ln |  file_type |attribute
--------------------------------
A  |  1  |  cat1     |abc
A  |  2  |  cat1     |gth
A  |  1  |  cat2     |fgh
B  |  1  |  cat2     |gth
```

and I want my final table to be with 2 initial rows and the file_type transposed

```
 fn |  ln |  cat1 | cat2
--------------------------------
 A  |   1 |  abc  | fgh
 A  |   2 |  gth  | 
 B  |   1 |       | gth
```

I have not been able to find what I need in functools ...

version is Postgres 9.3

Answer (score 4):

Use `crosstab()` from the additional module tablefunc.

The **specific difficulty** here is that the "row name" consists of two columns. I concatenate for the purpose of the query and do not display the concatenated column at the end.
Assuming `fn` and `ln` are `NOT NULL`. Untested:

```
SELECT fn, ln, cat1, cat2
FROM crosstab(
       'SELECT fn || ln AS row_name, fn, ln, file_type, attribute
        FROM   t
        ORDER  BY fn, ln, file_type'

      ,$$VALUES ('cat1'::text), ('cat2')$$)
AS t (row_name text, fn text, ln int, cat1 text, cat2 text);
```

Another option would be to add a surrogate "row name" with a window function like `dense_rank()` and treat the defining two columns as "extra columns". Example:

- [Postgresql crosstab query with multiple "row name" columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312739/postgresql-crosstab-query-with-multiple-row-name-columns/43313667#43313667)

Basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Comment: this is great solution if the extra cols are "expected to be the same" for *all* row_name. Is there a way to use crosstab for multilevel pivoting / hierarchical pivoting?

Comment: Ha! Found a solution in one of your [other answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32918155/481904). Except I used dense_rank() to generate surrogate key over groupings I wanted and then used it as row_name to crosstab.

Answer (score 1):

This is my typical fallback approach when pivoting in the database:

```
select fn,
       ln,
       max(case file_type when 'cat1' then attribute end),
       max(case file_type when 'cat2' then attribute end)
from testdata
group by fn,
         ln
;
```

If you remove the aggregates then you can see that the `case` expressions will be non-null only for the class's row with the specified category (and all other rows *should* be null for that class in that category, although this will silently just pick one if that's not the case). The `max` is just one way to pick the non-null value (you could use `min`, or any other aggregate that will pick a single non-null value out of a set).