# How to concat two columns

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

I need to concat two columns `firstname` and `lastname` as name in a crosstab select, example:

```
select * from crosstab('SELECT concat(u.firstname," ",u.lastname)as name
```

But I get this error:

```
column  « » doesn't exist.
```

How can I do it?

Comment: It depends on whether any `NULL` value can be involved and on your version of Postgres. [This recent `[crosstab]` answer deals with the same problem and may be of help.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21146080/939860)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from crosstab('SELECT  concat(u.firstname,'' '',u.lastname) as name')
```

I added a missing "close quote" at the end of your crosstab string, and I doubled-up the single quotes to escape them within that string.

Answer (score 2):

Replace double quote by simple quote like:

```
SELECT concat(u.firstname,' ',u.lastname)
```

Comment: Thank you I replaced it and gives error: sintax error in or near «',u.lastname) as name, if I run the query out of crosstab it is ok.