# Using ORDER BY in a crosstab() function

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, postgresql-9.1, pivot-table

Schema names: `"C_GT_Master"`,`"C_GT_Master"`. My table name is `items`.
Both schemas have the same table.

Fields: `itemno`, `itemname`, `unitno`.

I want to get details from `items` table in both schemas. Am using following code:

```
SELECT stckreport.* FROM public.crosstab('select itemname, ''GT'' anal,
itemno from  "C_GT_Master".items i 
union all 
select itemname, ''UnitNo'' anal,unitno from  "C_GT_Master".items i 
union all 
select itemname, ''New'' anal,itemno from  "G_New_Master".items i  
union all 
select itemname, ''UnitNo'' anal,unitno from  "G_New_Master".items i 
','select ''GT'' union all select ''New'' union all select ''UnitNo''') 
as stckreport 
(itemname text,GT text,New Text,UnitNo text)
```

This query returns:

```
 itemname  gt  new unitno
   AB           1    
   AB                1
   AB       1          
   AB                2
```

But I want:

```
itemname  gt   new  unitno
 AB             1    1
 AB       1          2
```

How to get that result using `crosstab()`. My real problem in a project is too big, so I explain it using this one table.

Am using **PostgreSQL 9.1.**

Comment: Please explain why you fold *some* of the `'AB'` rows, but not all. One row per schema? And it's always helpful to provide table definitions like what you get with `\d tbl` in psql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly and you want one row per schema, this modified `crosstab()` query should work:

```
SELECT  "schema", itemname, "GT", "New", "UnitNo"
FROM    public.crosstab($$
    SELECT 'c' || itemname, "C_GT_Master" AS sch, itemname
        , 'GT'::text AS anal, itemno FROM "C_GT_Master".items
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'c' || itemname, "C_GT_Master",  itemname
       , 'UnitNo', unitno FROM  "C_GT_Master".items
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'g' || itemname, "G_New_Master", itemname
        , 'New'   , itemno FROM  "G_New_Master".items
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'g' || itemname, "G_New_Master", itemname
        , 'UnitNo', unitno FROM  "G_New_Master".items
   ORDER BY 1$$

    ,$$VALUES ('GT'::text), ('New'), ('UnitNo')$$
   ) 
AS stckreport (
   item text, "schema" text, itemname text
 , "GT" text, "New" text, "UnitNo" text);
```

#### Major points

- Add `ORDER BY 1` in the first query string. That was your primary error.
- I concatenate a hash for the schema to the `itemname` to a value to group by resulting in one row per `(schema, itemname)`.
  In addition I add schema and `itemname` separately to have both in the result. Only select those in the outer `SELECT` for display. More details about "additional columns":
  [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)
  And about concatenating a row name:
  [crosstab with 2 (or more) row names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142765/crosstab-with-2-or-more-row-names/21146080#21146080)
- Use dollar-quoting to make your life easier.
- Use a `VALUES` expression for the second query string.
- More details in my basic go-to answer for `crosstab()`:
  [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Answer (score 1):

Try to group by result on itemname & unitno column, following is example of sql server,

```
With CTE as
(
SELECT stckreport.* FROM public.crosstab('select itemname, ''GT'' anal,
itemno from  "C_GT_Master".items i 
union all 
select itemname, ''UnitNo'' anal,unitno from  "C_GT_Master".items i 
union all 
select itemname, ''New'' anal,itemno from  "G_New_Master".items i  
union all 
select itemname, ''UnitNo'' anal,unitno from  "G_New_Master".items i 
','select ''GT'' union all select ''New'' union all select ''UnitNo''') 
as stckreport 
(itemname text,GT text,New Text,UnitNo text)
)
select itemname,sum(DT),SUM(New),UnitNo from CTE
group by itemname,UnitNo
order by itemname,UnitNo
```

Comment: Gt,New is text column then how can i do sum

Comment: OK. but they will have values like "1" or what?

Comment: "1" its a text. because my original values looks like

Comment: Even though Gt & New are text columns, will they have integer value alwas?

Comment: select record convert datatable. then assign the datasource. so i want to some work after the assign datasource. so i want text column only so i take like this

Comment: Then I think,I am Not clear with question, so my provided ans will not work for you.

Comment: my column type is text. So i can't use sum. Thanks for your valuable time. plz check my current answer and my expecting answer.

Comment: pls provide schema of you table.

Comment: I Tried Like this in your query `select itemname,sum(cast(GT as double precision)),SUM(cast(New as double precision)), sum(cast(UnitNo as double precision)) from CTE
group by itemname,UnitNo
order by itemname,UnitNo` but tha time also it returns twice

Comment: Schema means. Sorry Sir. What is schema

Comment: Hey friend, don't call as Sir. Schema means you table structure.If possible pls share some dummy data also.

Comment: ok but my real query have more than 10 tables and it has neary 12 union all query's. my original query is toooo big. that query take 7 page in word doc. so how can post it and explain it.