# Crosstab function in Postgres returning a one row output when I expect multiple rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table, crosstab, window-functions

I currently have a table `m` of the following format:

```
id    scenario    period    ct
2        1          1       1  
2        1          2       1
2        1          3       1
2        1          4       1
2        2          1       1
2        2          2       1
2        2          3       1
2        2          4       1
2        3          1       1
2        3          2       1
2        3          3       1
2        3          4       1
```

I want to create the following table:

```
id    scenario    period    1    2    3    4
2        1          1       1
2        1          2            1
2        1          3                 1
2        1          4                      1
2        2          1       1
2        2          2            1
2        2          3                 1
2        2          4                      1
2        3          1       1
2        3          2            1
2        3          3                 1
2        3          4                      1
```

The tablefunc extension has been created in my Postgres database already. I'm currently trying to use the `crosstab()` function to complete the pivot. However, I'm getting a table that looks like the following:

```
id    scenario    period    1    2   3    4 
2        1          1       1    1   1    1
```

The query I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
        'SELECT id, scenario, period, ct FROM m 
            ORDER BY 1',
         'SELECT DISTINCT period FROM m 
            ORDER BY 1')
AS (id, scenario, period, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: The query you present is plain invalid. (column definition list is missing data types). What's the actual query you tried?

Comment: My dataset is much larger, but I wanted a simpler example to show. I believe the more correct query would be: 

SELECT * FROM crosstab(
  'SELECT id, scenario, period, ct FROM m 
    ORDER BY 1',
   'SELECT DISTINCT period FROM m 
    ORDER BY 1')
AS (id int, scenario int , period int, "1" int, "2" int, "3" int, "4" int);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query generates your desired output:

```
SELECT id, scenario, period, p1, p2, p3, p4  -- all except aux column rn
FROM   crosstab(
  'SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id, scenario, period)::int AS rn
        , id, scenario, period, period, ct
   FROM   m
   ORDER  BY 1'
, 'VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)'
   ) AS (rn int, id int, scenario int, period int, p1 int, p2 int, p3 int, p4 int);
```

Two special difficulties:

1. You don't have a single unique column for the *row_name* yet. I use `row_number()` to generate the surrogate key: `rn`. I removed it from the outer `SELECT` to match your desired result.
   The way you tried it, `id` is taken to be the *row_name* and all input rows are aggregated into a single output row.
2. You want additional columns (`scenario` and `period`) in the result, which must come after the *row_name* and before the *category*. You must list `period` *twice* to get the original column additionally - redundant as though it may seem.

Basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

Related to this particular case:

- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)

---

Typically, you would have a query like this:

```
SELECT id, scenario, p1, p2, p3, p4  -- all except aux column rn
FROM   crosstab(
  'SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY id, scenario)::int AS rn
        , id, scenario, period, ct
   FROM   m
   ORDER  BY 1'
, 'VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4)'
   ) AS (rn int, id int, scenario int, p1 int, p2 int, p3 int, p4 int);
```

With an output like this:

```
id   scenario   p1   p2   p3   p4
2    1          1    1    1    1
2    2          1    1    1    1
2    3          1    1    1    1
```

Note the use of `rank()` instead of `row_number()` to group same combinations of `(id, scenario)` together.
The result makes more sense if counts are not all `1`.

Comment: Hi Erwin,

Thanks for answering my question! I have a follow-up question regarding the crosstab function. It turns out I want my crosstab function to specify value columns by selecting IDs from another table (the second parameter of my crosstab function would be "SELECT id_prod FROM prod;"). How might I alter the end of my query (after AS (rn int,... ) ) to correctly show the results from this change?