# Postgresql crosstab query with multiple "row name" columns

Tags: postgresql, crosstab, postgresql-9.4

I have a table that is a "tall skinny" fact table:

```
CREATE TABLE facts(
    eff_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    update_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    symbol_id int4 NOT NULL,
    data_type_id int4 NOT NULL,
    source_id char(3) NOT NULL,
    fact decimal
 /* Keys */
  CONSTRAINT fact_pk
    PRIMARY KEY (source_id, symbol_id, data_type_id, eff_date),
)
```

I'd like to "pivot" this for a report, so the header looks like this:

```
eff_date, symbol_id, source_id, datatypeValue1, ... DatatypeValueN
```

I.e., I'd like a row for each unique combination of eff_date, symbol_id, and source_id.

However, the postgresql crosstab() function only allow on key column.

Any ideas?

Comment: ... sample data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`crosstab()` expects the following columns from its input query (1st parameter), in this order:

1. a `row_name`
2. (optional) `extra` columns
3. a `category` (matching values in 2nd crosstab parameter)
4. a `value`

You don't have a `row_name`. Add a surrogate `row_name` with the window function [`dense_rank()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE).

Your question leaves room for interpretation. Let's add **sample rows for demonstration**:

```
INSERT INTO facts (eff_date, update_date, symbol_id, data_type_id, source_id)
VALUES
   (now(), now(), 1,  5, 'foo')
 , (now(), now(), 1,  6, 'foo')
 , (now(), now(), 1,  7, 'foo')
 , (now(), now(), 1,  6, 'bar')
 , (now(), now(), 1,  7, 'bar')
 , (now(), now(), 1, 23, 'bar')
 , (now(), now(), 1,  5, 'baz')
 , (now(), now(), 1, 23, 'baz');  -- only two rows for 'baz'
```

#### Interpretation #1: first *N* values

You want to list *the first N values* of `data_type_id` (the smallest, if there are more) for each distinct `(source_id, symbol_id, eff_date)`.

For this, you also need a synthetic `category`, can be synthesized with [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE). The basic query to produce input to `crosstab()`:

```
SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY eff_date, symbol_id, source_id)::int AS row_name
     , eff_date, symbol_id, source_id                                   -- extra columns
     , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY eff_date, symbol_id, source_id
                          ORDER BY data_type_id)::int                   AS category
     , data_type_id                                                     AS value  
FROM   facts
ORDER  BY row_name, category;
```

Crosstab query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
  'SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY eff_date, symbol_id, source_id)::int AS row_name
        , eff_date, symbol_id, source_id                                   -- extra columns
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY eff_date, symbol_id, source_id
                             ORDER BY data_type_id)::int                   AS category
        , data_type_id                                                     AS value  
   FROM   facts
   ORDER  BY row_name, category'
, 'VALUES (1), (2), (3)'
   ) AS (row_name int, eff_date timestamp, symbol_id int, source_id char(3)
       , datatype_1 int, datatype_2 int, datatype_3 int);
```

Results:

> ```
> row_name | eff_date       | symbol_id | source_id | datatype_1 | datatype_2 | datatype_3
> -------: | :--------------| --------: | :-------- | ---------: | ---------: | ---------:
>        1 | 2017-04-10 ... |         1 | bar       |          6 |          7 |         23
>        2 | 2017-04-10 ... |         1 | baz       |          5 |         23 |       null
>        3 | 2017-04-10 ... |         1 | foo       |          5 |          6 |          7
> ```

#### Interpretation #2: actual values in column names

You want to append actual values of `data_type_id` to the column names `datatypeValue1, ... DatatypeValueN`. One ore more of these:

```
SELECT DISTINCT data_type_id FROM facts ORDER BY 1;
```

`5, 6, 7, 23` in the example. Then actual display values can be just `boolean` (or the redundant value?). Basic query:

```
SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY eff_date, symbol_id, source_id)::int AS row_name
     , eff_date, symbol_id, source_id                                   -- extra columns
     , data_type_id                                                     AS category
     , TRUE                                                             AS value
FROM   facts
ORDER  BY row_name, category;
```

Crosstab query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
  'SELECT dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY eff_date, symbol_id, source_id)::int AS row_name
        , eff_date, symbol_id, source_id                                   -- extra columns
        , data_type_id                                                     AS category
        , TRUE                                                             AS value
   FROM   facts
   ORDER  BY row_name, category'
, 'VALUES (5), (6), (7), (23)'  -- actual values
   ) AS (row_name int, eff_date timestamp, symbol_id int, source_id char(3)
       , datatype_5 bool, datatype_6 bool, datatype_7 bool, datatype_23 bool);
```

Result:

> ```
> eff_date       | symbol_id | source_id | datatype_5 | datatype_6 | datatype_7 | datatype_23
> :--------------| --------: | :-------- | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :----------
> 2017-04-10 ... |         1 | bar       | null       | t          | t          | t          
> 2017-04-10 ... |         1 | baz       | t          | null       | null       | t          
> 2017-04-10 ... |         1 | foo       | t          | t          | t          | null
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=95b220e1ca7b918e043ebc287a9e0bd6)*

Related:

- [Crosstab function in Postgres returning a one row output when I expect multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917810/crosstab-function-in-postgres-returning-a-one-row-output-when-i-expect-multiple/32918155#32918155)
- [Dynamic alternative to pivot with CASE and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334)
- [Postgres - Transpose Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns/23061730#23061730)